# nifi: How to specify dynamic index name when sending data to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I am new to apache NiFi.

I am trying to put data into elasticsearch using nifi.

I want to specify an index name by combining a specific string and the value converted from a timestamp field into date format.

I was able to create the desired shape with the expression below, but failed to create the index name with the value of the timestamp field of the content.

```
${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd')}
```

- example json data

```
{
 "timestamp" :1625579799000,
  "data1": "abcd",
  "date2": 12345
}
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
index : "myindex-2021.07.06"
```

What should I do? please tell me how

Comment: All of the `PutElasticsearchX` processors have an `Index` property to set in the configuration. In this property, put the value `myindex-${now():format('yyyy-MM-dd')}` and it will use `myindex-2021-07-06` as the Index. If the Index doesn't already exist, you will need to either manually create it or enable index auto creation in Elastic. The content of your data is not used for this timestamp, `now()` gets the current timestamp of the machine in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I know that if you use the PutElasticSearch Processor, you can provide it with a specific index name to use. And as long as the index name meets the proper ElasticSearch format for naming a new index, if the enable auto index creation in ElasticSearch is turned on, then when sent, Elastic will create the new index with the desired name. This has worked for me. Double check the Elastic Naming Rules that can be found [here](https://linuxhint.com/elasticsearch-create-index) or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-indexing.html